# Check value of multiple object properties and remove them

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a data set in this format:

```
{
  roof: 'black',
  door: 'white',
  windows: 8
},
{
  roof: 'red',
  door: 'green',
  windows: 2
},
{
  roof: 'black',
  door: 'green',
  windows: 8
}
```

And I want to remove every key/value pair where `roof: 'black'`, `door: 'green'` and `windows: 2`, from each object. What I've done is the following:

```
if (object.roof == 'black'){
  delete object.roof;
}

if (object.windows == 2){
  delete object.windows;
}

if (object.door == 'green'){
  delete object.door;
}
```

But it feels kind of ugly. Is there any other, better, way to achieve this?

Comment: do you want to check `door` and delete `windows`property?

Comment: No, I want to delete `roof: 'black'` from the object, if the object has `roof: 'black'`

Comment: i mean the third check.

Comment: Ah, no, that was a copy paste mistake. Fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for the key value/pairs and remove the properties with a previous check.

```js
var array = [{ roof: 'black', door: 'white', windows: 8 }, { roof: 'red', door: 'green', windows: 2 }, { roof: 'black', door: 'green', windows: 8 }],
    remove = { roof: 'black', windows: 2, door: 'green' };

array.forEach(o => 
    Object.entries(remove).forEach(([k, v]) =>
        o[k] === v && Reflect.deleteProperty(o, k)));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```